# where can i download wxPython? i have Ubuntu

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, download, wxpython

I have Ubuntu, and i tried to download the GUI wxPython from synaptic (the name of the package is python-wxgtk 2.6), but it doesn't work.
Someone knows a way to download it from the terminal or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Instructions here http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian

Answer (score 0):

See http://wxpython.org/download.php or http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian. Unfortunately, the latest versions of wxPython have NOT been packaged in a .deb file as of yet, so if you want the latest in either the 2.8 or 2.9 series, you'll have to follow the BUILD instructions:

- Build 2.9: http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php
- Build 2.8: http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

at least, thats what worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try instructions at the [page](http://19shanu91.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/install-wxpython-on-12-04/). Just a simple Command line code.